# Jekyll like Pretty-Permalink in Yeoman

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll, yeoman

In Yeoman,

I want to work on "file1.html", "file2.html" and have them generated as "file1/index.html" and "file2/index.html". How do I do this?

EDIT:

I think I finally understood the various tools and where Yeoman stood. I was expecting something which Yeoman was not supposed to do. Yeoman is a good tool to scaffold your project. For instance, I really like how I can use a Yeoman Generator such as [generator-jekyllrb](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb) to scaffold your yeoman powered project in Jekyll.

There are lots of other generators. Check them out. Life of a Web Designer is way easier these days.

Comment: Could you add a bit more information? Where do the files come from? Which tasks do you want to run on them? Where should they eventually go?